# repeat main Query for multiple values from the SubQuery

Tags: mysql

My table are

```
 login_table
    {
    varchar: User_id//primary key
    //other stuff
    }
   token_table
   {
    varchar token_table;//primary key
    varchar user_id
   }
   token_messages
   {varchar: Mes_id
   varchar: token_id;
    }
```

Now i want get a count of messages for each token under some user;
Like :

```
token_id Mes_count
1          5
5          12
6          0
7          4
```

Here 1 5 6 7 are the token of say user :deepu

Comment: Why the primary keys in your tables are `VARCHAR` whereas they all `id`'s??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select tm.token_id,count(*) as msg_cnt from 
token_messages tm inner join token_table t
on tm.token_id=t.token_id and t.user_id in(select user_id from login_table where user_name = 'deepu')
group by tm.token_id
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me ! I never expected this fast response. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT tm.token_id, COUNT(t.user_id) `Mes_count`
 FROM token_messages tm
 INNER JOIN token_table t ON tm.token_id = t.token_id
 INNER JOIN login_table l ON t.user_id = l.user_id
 WHERE l.user_name = 'deepu'
 GROUP BY tm.token_id
```